# changing a date with biweekly data MYSQL

Tags: mysql, load, subquery, datatables

I have downloaded a file that has biweekly data.  Since no program includes option to handle such format, I have tweaked my own function to load such format.  The code looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL  
INFILE '/my_folder/servicios.csv' 
INTO TABLE SERVICIOS
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 2 LINES
(@periodo, MERCANCIAS, SERVICIOS, INPC, ENERGETICOS)
SET PERIODO = (SELECT IF(DAY(ld.prd) = 2, ADDDATE(ld.prd,14), ld.prd) 
        FROM (SELECT DATE(@periodo) AS prd) ld);
```

What the SET statement does is to keep '2014/10/01' for the first week as is, but turn '2014/10/02' for the second week to '2014/10/16'.

I understood that I can include subqueries in SET section of LOAD DATA statement.  However, all I get are NULL values.  If I do the query outside I get the right thing.  Can anyone point me where I'm failing?

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that what I was taking as a string, could be a date as well.  For a simple replace this was fixed with:

```
SET PERIODO = IF(DAY(@periodo) = 2, ADDDATE(@periodo,14), @periodo);
```

However, if this problem is will be encountered more than once, I found create a user_function will look cleaner and scalable to other options.  Something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION BIWEEK_DATE(datein DATE)
RETURNS DATE
BEGIN 
SET @biweek  = DAY(datein);
SET @dateout = CASE @biweek
               WHEN 1 THEN datein
               WHEN 2 THEN ADDDATE(datein, INTERVAL 14 DAY)
                      ELSE NULL END;
END CASE;
RETURN @dateout;
END $$
```